# World Oceans Day — why is it plural?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, possessives

Today is the World Oceans Day. Why is ‘World Ocean’ in it plural? There is only one World Ocean. Or did they just omit the apostrophe before the *-s*?

Comment: Thursday June 3rd was apparently World Bicycle Day. Since there exist more than 1 bicycle, one might expect a plural-form attributive noun, but the usual singular-form attributive works fine and sounds less comical. But note that the composition is _World [Bicycle Day]_, when the world (standing for all its inhabitants) is invited to celebrate the venerable bike. There's not a _World Bicycle_. Likewise, _World [Oceans Day]_. 'Ocean' would certainly have worked, but it's good to think of the contiguous supersea as being made up of 4 or 5 'separate' oceans (or if you write shanties, 7 seas).

Comment: Because most people don't distinguish between the global ocean and the various ocean basins. If you ask people how many oceans there are, very few will say just one.

Comment: No, there are four oceans (I haven't heard of the Southern Ocean) and the World Ocean which is made up by them.

Comment: I think I've got the point now: as I see now there is no such term in English as there is in Russian (Мировой океан). Thanks to all for answering and commenting on my question!

Comment: It is not obvious what research the OP is supposed to have done before asking the question. The question concerns a syntactical ambiguity, not something that can be resolved by consulting a dictionary.

Comment: I'm guessing they want to emphasise the fact that they're concerned with all the oceans in the world, rather than just being concerned with some small part of the sea or a particular aspect of oceanography. But if you want to know for sure you'll have to ask them - this isn't really a question of English usage but of the particular name of an organisation where there are several grammatical options.

Comment: @jsw29 research would presumably have involved googling and then reading https://www.un.org/en/observances/oceans-day

Comment: @StuartF this article doesn't explain the name. And I've got my diploma in oceanology.

Answer (score 3):

There are five oceans:

- Atlantic Ocean
- Pacific Ocean
- Indian Ocean
- Arctic Ocean
- Southern (Antarctic) Ocean

and they are all considered on World Oceans Day.

This isn't the same construct as "World Bicycle Day" because that doesn't consider **all the separate bicycles in the world**, but rather the concept of cycling.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126350/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-leach-world-oceans-day--why-is-it-plural).

Answer (score 0):

It would be "Всемирный день океанов" in Russian - we use the attributive in place of the genitive in English. The difference between the singular and plural comes across in Russian too - "Всемирный день океана" would have the same connotations as "World Ocean Day". That is to say ocean as a concept rather than all the oceans. Hope that helps.

Comment: There is no genitive in this English name. I figured it out yesterday (all you said), but thank you anyway.

Comment: Precisely my point. The genitive "океанов" in the Russian is an attributive in English.

Comment: Excuse my butting in, but this Stack is for English. There is a [russian.se] site.